# Thunderbird Account Configuration Cannot Be Verified

Tags: thunderbird

I have an error that is blocking me because I have already tried a multitude of solutions.

I guess the error is due to the fact that the account I want to add has A2F enabled.

I do have an application key, but how can I continue the process and add it?